# Internal Salesforce.com Error on site.com page

Tags: salesforce, apex

Question: We are receiving Internal Salesforce.com Error on site.com page on line number 457 .Please can anyone help to let me reason for the issues and how to resolve this. Thankyou. Code Snippet:

Set setOfConDocIDs = new Set(); List tskObjList = [SELECT Id, WhoId, Subject, ActivityDate, Status, OwnerId, Description, CreatedDate, TaskSubtype, Document_IDs_1__c, Document_IDs_2__c FROM Task where whatId =: accObj.id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC]; system.debug('tskObjList=== 222 > '+tskObjList); if(!tskObjList.isEmpty()){ if(tskObjList[0].Document_IDs_1__c != null){ String[] IDs = new String[]{}; IDs = tskObjList[0].Document_IDs_1__c.split(','); setOfConDocIDs.addAll(IDs); } if(tskObjList[0].Document_IDs_2__c != null){ String[] IDs = new String[]{}; IDs = tskObjList[0].Document_IDs_2__c.split(','); setOfConDocIDs.addAll(IDs); } } system.debug('@@@ setOfConDocIDs 22 : '+setOfConDocIDs);

Code ScreenShot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZz8e.png)

While executing the above highlighted line through site.com page it shows an error of Internal Salesforce.com Error on site.com page